# comparing contents of two lists python

Tags: python, list, compare

I am trying to compare 2 lists to see if they fundamentally have the same contents (in whatever order).
e.g.

```
x = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]

y = [4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 4]
```

How do I state that these 2 lists each have 1 1, 2 2s, 1 3, 2 4s and 1 5? (python version 3.6)

Comment: You can compare their sorted versions. `sorted(x) == sorted(y)` should work.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Why not compare sorted lists?